# Postgres infinite self join

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, go-gorm

So i have an article, and "comments" on the article..

the comment allows people to reply.. and you could reply to the reply.. so on and so forth, meaning the deepest tree root would be N

Quick mockup of what the tables look like

```
Comments(id, news_id, user_id, body, likes)

Replies(id, parent_id) --> id here is = Comments.id

User(id, username, password)

News(id, title, body, image)
```

Is there a way to query the Postgres DB to give me a result of something like

So anything inside the `Replies` table that has null parent_id is a "main" comment (aka isn't a reply).. I would love if possible if the `children` fields gets populated within itself (i.e. a reply of a reply)

Is this even possible with Postgres? Or Am i supposed to be fetching all `Replies` joining them with `Comments` and then iterating through each one trying to find it's proper desitination?

Btw, i'm using `GoLang` for my backend and the `Gorm` package to access my postgres db

**EDIT:**
I'm using this query

```
with recursive commentss as (
  select r.id, r.parent, array[r.id] as all_parents, 
         c.body, u.username 
    from replies r 
          inner join comments c 
                  on c.id = r.id 
                join users u 
                  on u.id = c.user_refer 
   where (parent <> '') IS NOT TRUE 
   union all 
  select r.id, r.parent, c.all_parents || r.id, 
         co.body, u.username 
    from replies r 
          join comments co 
            on co.id = r.id 
          join users u 
            on u.id = co.user_refer 
          join commentss c 
            on r.parent = c.id 
               and r.id <> ALL (c.all_parents)
  ) 
   select * from commentss order by all_parents;
```

Which results to :

[image]

Which is a step closer.. however what i need is to have a JSON object returned looking like

```
comments: [
  {
    comment_id: ...,
    username: ...,
    comment_body: ....,
    comment_likes: ....,
    children: [...]
  },
  {
    .....
  }
]
```

Where the first items inside the `comments` object would be the comments that are NOT a reply, and the `children` field should be populated with the replied comments.. and the comments inside the `children` should also have their `children` populated to replies to that reply

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: This will depend on your version. Research CTEs as this type of recursive query is exactly how you would do this query, provided your version supports them.

Comment: @Tomc This is the most i could come up with using CTE.. is there a better way to approach this or is JSON with sql a bad idea?

Comment: @GordonLinoff PING; more clear with this edit?

Comment: @MadoBaker Yes, but please provide some samole data which can we copy. So we are able to write a query. Otherwise we have to write it without the ability to check it

Comment: At least you are getting the data. turning it into nested json I dont know. Not familiar enough with Postgressql to help. Sorry, but hopefully someone else can help with that.

Comment: I am bit confused. In your screenshot you are selecting parents, in your JSON you want children. What are you searching for? If you want children, do you want direct children or all deeper children in the list as well?

Comment: If we consider Replies to be Comment on Comments and merge those tables with two extra fields parent_id and node_path, this could be achieved using ltree in postgres. Have a look at it [Use ltreee + plv8 to fetch hirarcical records as json](https://coderwall.com/p/z00-yw/use-ltreee-plv8-to-fetch-hirarcical-records-as-json). If you face difficulty do comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hoping that this is your expected result. (I did something similar here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52076212/3984221)

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=a8e17c41f4457080a7e697d7d2c229c7)

**Table `comments`**:

```
id  body          user_id  likes  
--  ------------  -------  -----  
a   foo           1        1      
b   foofoo        1        232    
c   foofoofoo     1        23232  
d   fooFOO        1        53     
e   cookies       1        864    
f   bar           1        44     
g   barbar        1        54     
h   barBAR        1        222    
i   more cookies  1        1
```

**Table `replies`**

```
id  parent_id  
--  ---------  
a   (null)     
b   a          
c   b          
d   a          
e   (null)     
f   (null)     
g   f          
h   f          
i   (null)
```

**Result**:

```
{
    "comments": [{
        "children": [],
        "username": "Mike Tyson",
        "comment_id": "i",
        "comment_body": "more cookies",
        "comment_likes": 1
    },
    {
        "children": [{
            "children": [],
            "username": "Mike Tyson",
            "comment_id": "b",
            "comment_body": "foofoo",
            "comment_likes": 232
        },
        {
            "children": [{
                "children": [],
                "username": "Mike Tyson",
                "comment_id": "c",
                "comment_body": "foofoofoo",
                "comment_likes": 23232
            }],
            "username": "Mike Tyson",
            "comment_id": "d",
            "comment_body": "fooFOO",
            "comment_likes": 53
        }],
        "username": "Mike Tyson",
        "comment_id": "a",
        "comment_body": "foo",
        "comment_likes": 1
    },
    {
        "children": [],
        "username": "Mike Tyson",
        "comment_id": "e",
        "comment_body": "cookies",
        "comment_likes": 864
    },
    {
        "children": [{
            "children": [],
            "username": "Mike Tyson",
            "comment_id": "g",
            "comment_body": "barbar",
            "comment_likes": 54
        },
        {
            "children": [],
            "username": "Mike Tyson",
            "comment_id": "h",
            "comment_body": "barBAR",
            "comment_likes": 222
        }],
        "username": "Mike Tyson",
        "comment_id": "f",
        "comment_body": "bar",
        "comment_likes": 44
    }]
}
```

**Query**:

***Recursion***:

```
WITH RECURSIVE parent_tree AS (
    SELECT 
        id, 
        NULL::text[] as parent_id,
        array_append('{comments}'::text[], (row_number() OVER ())::text) as path, 
        rc.children  
    FROM replies r
    LEFT JOIN LATERAL (SELECT parent_id, ARRAY_AGG(id) as children FROM replies WHERE parent_id = r.id GROUP BY parent_id) rc ON rc.parent_id = r.id
    WHERE r.parent_id IS NULL 

    UNION

    SELECT 
        r.id, 
        array_append(pt.parent_id, r.parent_id), 
        array_append(array_append(pt.path, 'children'), (row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY pt.parent_id))::text),
        rc.children      
    FROM parent_tree pt
    JOIN replies r ON r.id = ANY(pt.children)
    LEFT JOIN LATERAL (SELECT parent_id, ARRAY_AGG(id) as children FROM replies WHERE parent_id = r.id GROUP BY parent_id) rc ON rc.parent_id = r.id
), json_objects AS (
   SELECT c.id, jsonb_build_object('children', '[]'::jsonb, 'comment_id', c.id, 'username', u.name, 'comment_body', c.body, 'comment_likes', c.likes) as jsondata
   FROM comments c
   LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = c.user_id
)
SELECT 
    parent_id, 
    path,
    jsondata
FROM parent_tree pt 
LEFT JOIN json_objects jo ON pt.id = jo.id
ORDER BY parent_id NULLS FIRST
```

The only recursion part is within CTE `parent_tree`. Here I am searching for the parents and build a path. This path is needed for inserting the json data later at the right position.

The second CTE (`json_objects`) builds a json object for each comment with an empty children array where the children can be inserted later.

The `LATERAL` join searches the replies table for children of the current id and gives an array with their ids.

The `ORDER BY` clause at the end is important. With this it is ensured that all upper nodes come before the lower nodes (their children). Otherwise the input into the global json object could fail later because a necessary parent could not exist at the right moment.

***Building the final JSON object***:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION json_tree() RETURNS jsonb AS $$
DECLARE
    _json_output jsonb;
    _temprow record;
BEGIN

    SELECT 
        jsonb_build_object('comments', '[]'::jsonb) 
    INTO _json_output;

    FOR _temprow IN
        -- <query above>
    LOOP
        SELECT jsonb_insert(_json_output, _temprow.path, _temprow.jsondata) INTO _json_output;
    END LOOP;

    RETURN _json_output;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

It is not possible to build the json object within the recursion because within the query the `jsondata` object is not a global variable. So if I would add `b` as child into `a` in one recursion branch, it wouldn't exist in another branch where I would add `c` as child.

So it is necessary to generate a global variable. This could be done in a function. With the calculated path and child objects it is really simple to build the final json together: looping through the result set and add the json object into the path of the global object.

Comment: Apologies to coming back but i tried decoding it and couldn't figure it out, but whats the proper way to filter results by comment.news_id? as in only give me back the comments that have a specific comment.news_id

Comment: There are several ways to achieve this. You could do a filter within `json_objects` CTE and do an `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN` (which could be taken in this version as well.) That would filter out all expected results. You could do a join to `comments`at the end as well. But the greatest performance boost would be to do this in both recursion parts: join against the `comments` table and filter (but then you have to do it twice - in both recursion parts)

Comment: Apologies @S-man but I can't seem to figure it out.. I'm able to Filter all the "children" comments and get only the children comments of the news I want by doing this `LEFT JOIN LATERAL (SELECT parent, ARRAY_AGG(replies.id) as children FROM replies
INNER JOIN comments c ON c.id = r.id
WHERE parent = r.id AND c.news_id='8gl98XAig' GROUP BY parent)` on the first `LEFT JOIN LATERAL` however, i'm still getting all comments that have `parent` set to `NULL`

Comment: Please help me with that: Take my fiddle (or a new one) and add the news column to the data set. Then add your query. Run and post the new fiddle link with an explanation of the desired output as Edit into your question. Then I can check it properly

Comment: Okay So i got the query to filter out the results that I want, however the output from the for loop gives me back only one result? please take a look at this fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=729230933ce7b7d255e6440c482b9400

Comment: Hmmm, just found out if you change `news_id` to `=1` you will get wanted results.. Seems like if only 1 original comment (A comment without a parent) exists, it won't get populated

Comment: Figure out issue! JSON objects start their index at 0, not 1.. so when you were building the `path` field with their "index" it was always 1 higher than it's supposed to be... minusing `row_number() OVER ` by `1` fixes everything!! Thanks for the code