# Postgres LTREE display by grouping parents and children

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql, ltree

I have a sample Ltree Structure than I want to return it as JSON structure. 
I've tried searching on stack overflow but the results are giving wrong responses.

```sql
create table node
(
    id   integer not null,
    name varchar(255),
    path ltree   not null
);
```

and I have these data

```sql
INSERT INTO node (id,name,path) VALUES (1,'Residential','1');
INSERT INTO node (id,name,path) VALUES (2,'Commercial','2');
INSERT INTO node (id,name,path) VALUES (3,'Industrial','3');
INSERT INTO node (id,name,path) VALUES (4,'Res type 1','1.4');
INSERT INTO node (id,name,path) VALUES (5,'Comm type 1','2.5');
INSERT INTO node (id,name,path) VALUES (6,'Industrial 1','3.6');
INSERT INTO node (id,name,path) VALUES (7,'Residential 2','1.4.7');
INSERT INTO node (id,name,path) VALUES (8,'Commercial 2','2.5.8');
INSERT INTO node (id,name,path) VALUES (9,'Industrial 2','3.6.9');
```

and this is what I want to collect with my query

```
[
  {
    "name": "Residentioal",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Res type 1",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Residential 2",
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Commercial",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Comm type 1",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Commercial 2",
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Industrial",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Industrial 1",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Industrial 2",
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I tried `recursive with ..` but it keeps looping through without returning proper value.

Comment: Your ltree path do not fit your expected output. "commercial" is located under id 1 as well as "industrial 1". "industrial 2" is located under 3.6 which does not exist. I corrected the data in my example below.

Comment: @S-Man sorry there was typo from my side

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need two parts, the recursion one and additionally a function. I explained this already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52076212/3984221), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52642095/3984221) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52719855/3984221), so please have a look there for further explanations.

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=459496877ea048b8facf9e853645bf6c)

Recursion

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
    SELECT 
        id,
        name,
        path,
        json_build_object('name', name, 'children', ARRAY[]::text[]) AS jsonobject,
        ARRAY[]::text[] || (row_number() OVER () - 1)::text as jsonpath,
        0 as depth        
    FROM node
    WHERE path = subpath(path, 0, 1) --parents

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        n.id, 
        n.name, 
        n.path,
        json_build_object('name', n.name, 'children', ARRAY[]::text[]),
        jsonpath || '{children}' || (row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY subpath(n.path, depth, 1)::text ORDER BY subpath(n.path, depth + 1, 1)::text::int) - 1)::text,
        c.depth + 1
    FROM
        node n
    JOIN cte c 
    ON c.id = subpath(n.path, depth, 1)::text::int
       AND nlevel(n.path) = depth + 2 AND subpath(n.path, depth + 1, 1)::text::int = n.id
)
SELECT * FROM cte
```

The function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION nested_json() RETURNS jsonb AS $$
DECLARE
    _json_output jsonb;
    _temprow record;
BEGIN   
    _json_output := '[]'::jsonb;

    FOR _temprow IN
        -- <Add the CTE from above here>
    LOOP
        SELECT 
        jsonb_insert(
            _json_output, 
            _temprow.jsonpath, 
            _temprow.jsonobject
        )
        INTO _json_output;
    END LOOP;   

    RETURN _json_output;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

**Please notice:** The ltree structure is not a really good choice for this use case because you need to calculate the subpaths again and again. A simple reference to the parent would be more helpful and faster.

---

**Edit:** The db<>fiddle admin is great and installed the ltree extension, so there is a new fiddle

Comment: I'm running Postgres 9.5 and JSONB_INSERT is only available from 9.6 onwards, any replacement to that ?

Comment: @Bardia jsonb_set works as well in this case https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=e1d665cfd9f6dc7355d2352c9b470f6c

Comment: I did this based on other example that you provided, but there is small issue with that, If I have two or more parents with children, it assigns all to the first parent 
[SQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=006f7d607fd7698c1b8ae63ff3dd8b02)

Comment: @Bardia You are right. But with only one root as in your example it works fine https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=0a14f86fa4668cf5519f2f7ce52b50e9

Comment: @Bardia if it works for you please do not forget to upvote (which honors the work and time the repliers invested into you problem) and accept (which shows that the problem has been solved). Otherwise please tell me which change is needed.

Comment: @Bardia: dbfiddle now works with ltree. Adjusted the fiddle (thanks to db<>fiddle admin!)