# postgresql - building a tree with recursive and export that as json

Tags: sql, postgresql, tree, parent, recursive-query

I'm having issues on building a tree starting from a table. 
I'm following the [tutorial](https://tapoueh.org/blog/2018/01/exporting-a-hierarchy-in-json-with-recursive-queries/) from D.Fontaine but something is wrong in my query.

here is a subset of rows from this table:

```
abs=# select * from myproj_loparentrelation                                                                                                                                                                                            where root_id = '57b2e67b-5862-499a-a471-0f2f6b23440e' order by level ASC;
   id   |               root_id                | level | display_sequence |                lo_id                 |              parent_id
--------+--------------------------------------+-------+------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------
  90468 | 57b2e67b-5862-499a-a471-0f2f6b23440e |     2 |                1 | 5c51558b-1180-495f-88c3-f7af49bafcf3 | 57b2e67b-5862-499a-a471-0f2f6b23440e
  55209 | 57b2e67b-5862-499a-a471-0f2f6b23440e |     2 |               16 | 3962f997-9e14-4cac-a95f-dc20c077a531 | 57b2e67b-5862-499a-a471-0f2f6b23440e
  14890 | 57b2e67b-5862-499a-a471-0f2f6b23440e |     3 |               17 | 0f335cd1-74d0-4a5e-831d-1aba0c0dc396 | 3962f997-9e14-4cac-a95f-dc20c077a531
 116513 | 57b2e67b-5862-499a-a471-0f2f6b23440e |     3 |                4 | 78b6cac3-307f-449a-bb3c-fe4442f4d1e8 | 5c51558b-1180-495f-88c3-f7af49bafcf3
 122691 | 57b2e67b-5862-499a-a471-0f2f6b23440e |     3 |                6 | 7ecb01da-078a-49b9-b488-86dc6bb24ab4 | 5c51558b-1180-495f-88c3-f7af49bafcf3
  95729 | 57b2e67b-5862-499a-a471-0f2f6b23440e |     3 |               14 | 62e889fe-b0e6-4fd4-a89f-512a1f31e210 | 5c51558b-1180-495f-88c3-f7af49bafcf3
 141390 | 57b2e67b-5862-499a-a471-0f2f6b23440e |     3 |                2 | 932353b7-bb63-4bad-87e7-70bcebcbbc98 | 5c51558b-1180-495f-88c3-f7af49bafcf3
  96022 | 57b2e67b-5862-499a-a471-0f2f6b23440e |     3 |               26 | 6346657d-a41e-45ab-87bc-abf32a8c616c | 3962f997-9e14-4cac-a95f-dc20c077a531
  61116 | 57b2e67b-5862-499a-a471-0f2f6b23440e |     4 |               22 | 3f07cece-0a7c-411e-b7d1-0370d18c6405 | 0f335cd1-74d0-4a5e-831d-1aba0c0dc396
  72097 | 57b2e67b-5862-499a-a471-0f2f6b23440e |     4 |                5 | 49c43039-84e6-4f36-a8a1-5f57ad1bc67e | 78b6cac3-307f-449a-bb3c-fe4442f4d1e8
  81260 | 57b2e67b-5862-499a-a471-0f2f6b23440e |     4 |               15 | 51e9ce01-9c90-437a-b17c-8b0b19c3a2b4 | 62e889fe-b0e6-4fd4-a89f-512a1f31e210
  84177 | 57b2e67b-5862-499a-a471-0f2f6b23440e |     4 |               12 | 553150c1-ff43-44e0-a52d-d6361813de73 | 7ecb01da-078a-49b9-b488-86dc6bb24ab4
  89331 | 57b2e67b-5862-499a-a471-0f2f6b23440e |     4 |               24 | 5b1ede40-66a6-4320-be79-69f0a4d0340e | 0f335cd1-74d0-4a5e-831d-1aba0c0dc396
 111377 | 57b2e67b-5862-499a-a471-0f2f6b23440e |     4 |               21 | 73f05e3c-012e-4b41-acc0-14791c83f710 | 0f335cd1-74d0-4a5e-831d-1aba0c0dc396
 114868 | 57b2e67b-5862-499a-a471-0f2f6b23440e |     4 |               33 | 778bf627-e83f-4385-bbb9-3537d45d18b6 | 6346657d-a41e-45ab-87bc-abf32a8c616c
 129785 | 57b2e67b-5862-499a-a471-0f2f6b23440e |     4 |               27 | 8650b402-bb6f-4be2-9585-800d189ded83 | 6346657d-a41e-45ab-87bc-abf32a8c616c
 151263 | 57b2e67b-5862-499a-a471-0f2f6b23440e |     4 |               10 | 9f29806f-d04d-4952-9743-9b2eedeecfee | 7ecb01da-078a-49b9-b488-86dc6bb24ab4
 152546 | 57b2e67b-5862-499a-a471-0f2f6b23440e |     4 |               34 | a0958fb5-21c2-440b-8dc9-02659b34691e | 6346657d-a41e-45ab-87bc-abf32a8c616c
 158562 | 57b2e67b-5862-499a-a471-0f2f6b23440e |     4 |               13 | a7f96063-e78e-4248-a512-68d726b0ff09 | 7ecb01da-078a-49b9-b488-86dc6bb24ab4
 165779 | 57b2e67b-5862-499a-a471-0f2f6b23440e |     4 |                7 | aeacbddd-37d6-4eda-9695-bace3406f415 | 7ecb01da-078a-49b9-b488-86dc6bb24ab4
 177880 | 57b2e67b-5862-499a-a471-0f2f6b23440e |     4 |               28 | bc18337c-899c-416b-91e4-93e4c7699d58 | 6346657d-a41e-45ab-87bc-abf32a8c616c
 188650 | 57b2e67b-5862-499a-a471-0f2f6b23440e |     4 |               11 | c6a82ea7-2156-492e-9f0f-a73c36afba70 | 7ecb01da-078a-49b9-b488-86dc6bb24ab4
 204117 | 57b2e67b-5862-499a-a471-0f2f6b23440e |     4 |               30 | d7924927-55c3-4085-bdd6-5420ef7162a9 | 6346657d-a41e-45ab-87bc-abf32a8c616c
  10528 | 57b2e67b-5862-499a-a471-0f2f6b23440e |     4 |               19 | 0be4c51c-3d52-499e-98fb-3dac9b2b1e49 | 0f335cd1-74d0-4a5e-831d-1aba0c0dc396
 223079 | 57b2e67b-5862-499a-a471-0f2f6b23440e |     4 |                3 | ebb92498-a730-4b61-b1dd-44696aae4a8e | 932353b7-bb63-4bad-87e7-70bcebcbbc98
  11987 | 57b2e67b-5862-499a-a471-0f2f6b23440e |     4 |               29 | 0ccd9922-85fa-45de-bd87-257b77e2a5a3 | 6346657d-a41e-45ab-87bc-abf32a8c616c
  22808 | 57b2e67b-5862-499a-a471-0f2f6b23440e |     4 |               32 | 17f12743-e0c4-4f32-a1d6-0e680fa762d5 | 6346657d-a41e-45ab-87bc-abf32a8c616c
  28627 | 57b2e67b-5862-499a-a471-0f2f6b23440e |     4 |               31 | 1eb6653a-de11-42a2-9766-4222996ff75e | 6346657d-a41e-45ab-87bc-abf32a8c616c
  35421 | 57b2e67b-5862-499a-a471-0f2f6b23440e |     4 |               20 | 26418eb9-22d4-41f4-a117-ae1884987080 | 0f335cd1-74d0-4a5e-831d-1aba0c0dc396
  36110 | 57b2e67b-5862-499a-a471-0f2f6b23440e |     4 |               25 | 27198280-5cff-462c-87be-5fb8b6a7b309 | 0f335cd1-74d0-4a5e-831d-1aba0c0dc396
  46312 | 57b2e67b-5862-499a-a471-0f2f6b23440e |     4 |               23 | 319838f6-aebc-460e-ae77-009858f2f858 | 0f335cd1-74d0-4a5e-831d-1aba0c0dc396
  48878 | 57b2e67b-5862-499a-a471-0f2f6b23440e |     4 |                9 | 33bf5a6f-5b72-4bf0-9e1b-a68f7ad69a64 | 7ecb01da-078a-49b9-b488-86dc6bb24ab4
```

- root is `57b2e67b-5862-499a-a471-0f2f6b23440e`
- under the root, there are two children `5c51558b-1180-495f-88c3-f7af49bafcf3` and `3962f997-9e14-4cac-a95f-dc20c077a531`
- each one of those has other children and so on.

the expected result would be something like:

```
[ 
   {'Name': '57b2e67b-5862-499a-a471-0f2f6b23440e', 
    'Sub Classes': [ 
         {'Name': '5c51558b-1180-495f-88c3-f7af49bafcf3', 
          'Subclasses': [ 

           ]}, 
          {'Name': '3962f997-9e14-4cac-a95f-dc20c077a531', 
          'Subclasses': [ 
                {'Name': '5c51558b-1180-495f-88c3-f7af49bafcf3', 
                 'Subclasses': [ 
                       ... 
                 ]} 
          ]} 
      } 
]
```

but it's not so I'm messing up something. here's the query:

```
with recursive rels_from_parents as 
( 
      select sel.lo_id, '{}'::uuid[] as parents, sel.level as _level 
        from (select * from myproj_loparentrelation where root_id = '57b2e67b-5862-499a-a471-0f2f6b23440e') as sel 
       where sel.parent_id = sel.root_id 
   union all 
      select c.lo_id, parents || c.parent_id, c.level as _level 
        from      rels_from_parents p 
             join myproj_loparentrelation c 
               on c.parent_id = p.lo_id 
       where not c.lo_id = any(parents) 
), 
rels_from_children as 
( 
     select c.parent_id, 
            json_agg(jsonb_build_object('lo_id', c.lo_id::text))::jsonb as js 
       from rels_from_parents tree 
            join myproj_loparentrelation c using(lo_id) 
      where level > 0 and not lo_id = any(parents) 
   group by c.parent_id 
  union all 
     select c.parent_id, 
               jsonb_build_object('Name', c.lo_id::text) 
            || jsonb_build_object('Sub Classes', js) as js 
       from rels_from_children tree 
            join myproj_loparentrelation c on c.lo_id = tree.parent_id 
) 
    select jsonb_pretty(jsonb_agg(js)) 
    from rels_from_children;
```

can anyone provide help with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=102aeb122e11867cac8a2935d6526acd)

```
WITH RECURSIVE tree(lo_id, ancestor, child, path, json) AS  (
  SELECT 
      t1.lo_id, 
      NULL::text, 
      t2.lo_id,
      '{Subclasses}'::text[] || (row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.lo_id ORDER BY t2.display_sequence) - 1)::text,
      jsonb_build_object('Name', t2.lo_id, 'Subclasses', array_to_json(ARRAY[]::text[]))
  FROM test t1
  LEFT JOIN test t2 ON t1.lo_id = t2.parent_id
  WHERE t1.parent_id IS NULL

  UNION

  SELECT
      t1.lo_id, 
      t1.parent_id, 
      t2.lo_id,
      tree.path || '{Subclasses}' || (row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.lo_id ORDER BY t2.display_sequence) - 1)::text, 
      jsonb_build_object('Name', t2.lo_id, 'Subclasses', array_to_json(ARRAY[]::text[]))
  FROM test t1
  LEFT JOIN test t2 ON t1.lo_id = t2.parent_id
  INNER JOIN tree ON (t1.lo_id = tree.child)
  WHERE t1.parent_id = tree.lo_id
)
SELECT 
    child as lo_id, path, json 
FROM tree 
WHERE child IS NOT NULL ORDER BY path
```

Since you cannot fill a final JSON object in a recursive structure, you'll need a function for holding a global variable:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION json_tree() RETURNS jsonb AS $$
DECLARE
    _json_output jsonb;
    _temprow record;
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        jsonb_build_object('Name', lo_id, 'Subclasses', array_to_json(ARRAY[]::text[])) 
    INTO _json_output 
    FROM test 
    WHERE parent_id IS NULL;

    FOR _temprow IN
        -- <the query from above>
    LOOP
        SELECT jsonb_insert(_json_output, _temprow.path, _temprow.json) INTO _json_output;
    END LOOP;

    RETURN _json_output;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Because the solution is quiet similar as this one, please look [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52076212/3984221) for further explanation.