# Nested leaf node

Tags: sql, postgresql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I've stored a tree that contains multiple nodes. Every record in that table represents a node and its parent-node, as follows:

| node_id | parent_id |
| --- | --- |
| A | null |
| B | A |
| C | A |
| D | B |
| E | B |

As a result, the visual tree would look like this: [tree-nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQivS.png)

My goal is to create a function that'll hold the JSON path for every leaf in the tree. So for my current table, the result should behave as shown below:

| leaf_id | json_path |
| --- | --- |
| C | {"name": "A", "children": [{ "name": "C", "children": [] }] } |
| D | {"name": "A", "children": [{ "name": "B", "children": [{ "name": "D", "children": [] }] }] } |
| E | {"name": "A", "children": [{ "name": "B", "children": [{ "name": "E", "children": [] }] }] } |

There's already a question with a function that does the format I'm trying to achieve (link below):
[nested-json-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52071235/postgres-convert-adjacency-list-to-nested-json-object/52076212#52076212).
However, the written function selects the entire tree. Therefore, as I mentioned above, I need the path of every leaf node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a recursive `cte`:

```
with recursive cte(id, l, js) as (
   select t.node_id, t.node_id, jsonb_build_object('name', t.node_id, 'children', '[]'::jsonb) from tbl t 
   where not exists (select 1 from tbl t1 where t1.parent_id = t.node_id)
   union all
   select t3.parent_id, t3.l, jsonb_build_object('name', t3.parent_id, 'children', t3.js) 
   from (select t2.parent_id, t2.l, jsonb_agg(t2.js) js  
         from (select t1.parent_id, c.l, c.js from tbl t1 
         join cte c on c.id = t1.node_id) t2 group by t2.parent_id, t2.l) t3
)
select l leaf_id, v json_path from cte 
cross join jsonb_array_elements(js -> 'children') v where id is null
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-scNVKgT)